# Showing every $p$-subgroup of order $p^i$ is in a subgroup of order $p^{i+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be the largest positive integer such that $p^k \mid |G|$ and let $|H|=p^i$ where $0<i < k$. What should I prove to say that $H \subset H_1$ where $|H_1|=p^{i+1}$, and what guarantees the existence of $H_1$?

Comment: We have had such a question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150534/show-a-certain-group-is-contained-in-a-sylow-p-group

Comment: @Cocopuffs Thank you but,I'm not looking for a solution, I'm trying to find a way to continue my method.

Comment: I think you want $0\le i\lt k$, not $0\lt i\le k$.

Comment: @MJD yes that is true, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints from J.D.Dixon. I found them for you:

- Write the order of $G$ as $|G|=|Px_1H|+|Px_2H|+...+|Px_sH|$ for some elements $x_i\in G$.
- If $|P|=p^r$ then $p^{r+1}$ does not divide $|G|$.
- So there is some double coset $PxH$ that $p^{r+1}$ does not divide its order.
- Use the point that $|PxH|=\frac{|P|}{[H:x^{-1}Px\cap H]}$
- $H$ is a $p-$ group.

Comment: This is a bit too advanced for me, as I have never worked with double cosets. I'll try to read about them on Wikipedia and get back to these hints. Thank you

Comment: Great hints, Babak. Good reference!

Comment: How are you?;-) I hope you slept blissfully! I will likely head to bed soon (almost midnight for me!)

Comment: @amWhy: So hurry. there is a warm and charming bed prepared for you. I slept well, and I hop you will have the same full of stars. ;-)

Comment: I miss you!! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: My tel line has not been implemented yet. I miss being in the site, with you, with others, doing Maths and....